# Find a function in $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $g$ be a function in $L^1$. I want to create a function $f \in L^\infty$. My idea is to define this function:

\begin{cases} \overline{g}/|g|, & \mbox{if }g \mbox {$\ne 0$} \\ 0, & \mbox{if }g\mbox{ =0}
\end{cases}
where
$$
\|f\|_{\infty}=\inf\big\{\alpha>0: \mu(\{x \in \Omega: |f(x)|>\alpha\})=0 \big\}.$$
Does the equality
$$|f(x)|= {|\overline{g}(x)|\over{|g(x)|}}=1
$$
imply $\|f\|_{\infty}=1$ and $f \in L^{\infty}$?

Comment: What does "right" mean here?

Comment: What does the function $g$ have to do with the problem?

Comment: the prof suggests us tuo use a function in $L^1$ to create a function in $L^\infty$

Comment: I mean you could just define $f(x)=\max \{|g(x)|, C  \}$ for any $C>0$. This way it even stays measurable and continuous (assuming $g $ was). However, without any requirements on $f$, there are many choices, but I doubt most of them are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any *measurable* function tbh. Since $g/\vert g\vert\in \{-1,1\}$ whenever $g\neq 0$ and since we set our function $0$ if $g=0$ the resulting function is bounded ie. in $L^\infty$.

Comment: It has to be measurable at least.

Comment: That's true @themaker. But I don't think anything else is required. Will edit, thx

Comment: And it is indeed easy to see, that the resulting map is measurable, since if g ist measurable then the sets $\{g>0\}<\{g<0\},\{g=0\}$ are measurable